# Android: Delete all sqlite rows NOT IN top 5

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a database for my leaderboard. Currently, I insert all scores into my leaderboard, and select the 5 highest scores to show on my app. I think it would take up too much room to never delete the other scores, so I would like to delete them. How can I do this?

Here's how I select the top 5 scores, ranked first by score and second by time if score is equal:

```
    public  Cursor gethmLeaderboard(SQLiteDatabase db){

    String[] columns = {TableInfo.LB_RANK, TableInfo.LB_SCORE, TableInfo.LB_TIME};

    Cursor c = db.query(TableInfo.TABLE_HM, null, null, null, null, null, TableInfo.LB_SCORE + " DESC, " + TableInfo.LB_TIME + " ASC", "5");
    return c;

}
```

Here's how I create my table:

```
public String CREATE_HMQUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TableInfo.TABLE_HM + "("
        + TableInfo.LB_RANK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 1 ," + TableInfo.LB_SCORE +
        " INT,"+ TableInfo.LB_TIME + " VARCHAR );";
```

I want to delete all rows NOT IN that query. How can I do that?

Edit:

I tried this query:

```
public String DEL_ALLBUTES = "DELETE FROM " +
        TableInfo.TABLE_HM + " WHERE " +
        TableInfo.LB_RANK + " NOT IN (SELECT " +
        TableInfo.LB_RANK + " FROM " +
        TableInfo.TABLE_HM + " ORDER BY " +
        TableInfo.LB_SCORE + " DESC, " +
        TableInfo.LB_TIME + " ASC LIMIT 5);";
```

In this format:

```
db.rawQuery(DEL_ALLBUTES, null);
```

But when I check the database there are still tons of rows so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your table needs to have some unique ID. Use that to identify the rows you want to keep:

```sql
DELETE FROM ES
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID
                 FROM ES
                 ORDER BY Score DESC, Time ASC
                 LIMIT 5);
```

Comment: Then you should use the correct table name, and a unique ID.

Comment: Sorry, I switched things around which may have been confusing. My new edit is what I am trying. It has a primary key ID as well.

Comment: "Rank" does not sound like the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can create temp table insert top 5 score into temp table and delete all table then insert temp table into main table.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TempES AS SELECT
    ID
FROM
    ES
ORDER BY
    Score DESC,
    Time ASC
LIMIT 5;

DELETE
FROM
    ES;

INSERT INTO ES SELECT
    *
FROM
    TempES;

DROP TABLE TempES;
```